# Simple Database BenchMarking

Tags: mysql, mongodb, jmeter, benchmarking

I want to do a simple crud benchmarking in mongodb and mysql. What would be the best way to achieve this. Now, I am using javascript in mongo shell and procedure in mysql shell for queries.

Also what would be the best option for concurrency test in both cases? JMeter could be an option, but havenot tested it yet.

Thanks! in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JMeter supports both:

1. MongoDB via [MongoDB Script Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#MongoDB_Script)
2. MySQL via [JDBC Request Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request)

Reference material:

- [Building a Database Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-db-test-plan.html#building) - for MySQL (in fact for any RDBMS which supports JDBC protocol)
- [How to Load Test MongoDB with JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-mongodb-jmeter) - for MongoDB